# Autodesk Forge API upload a file

Tags: c#, autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am new to FORGE API development and I'm trying to develop a console application to manage data with FORGE API,These are the steps I have followed so far

1.I have successfully registered  an APP on FORGE

2.Then I have acquired a OAuth token using 2-legged authorization.

3.After that I have successfully created a bucket on FORGE to upload my files

4.Finally I tried to upload a small text file to the bucket and it worked,but when I try to upload a revit file (around 18 MB) its getting an exception "More than one error".

This is the code I'm using to upload the file

```
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Demo revit file\sample.rvt";
            string url = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mybucket/objects/sample.rvt";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {



                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);        
                var response= client.PutAsync(url, new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filePath))).Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string res = response.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Response: " + res);
            }
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I would recommend you to use a higher level library to handle your REST requests. Implementing it "manually" with the basic HttpClient might require a fair piece of work in some cases. RestSharp is a pretty well established library that alleviates this task. You can take a look at my node.js sample, using the same parameters should work when using RestSharp: https://github.com/leefsmp/forge/blob/master/src/server/api/services/OssSvc.js#L189

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma hi there - is there a library produced by the autodesk team which is the equivalent of Googles libraries to make end point calls? e.g. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/?

Comment: Check out our Forge SDK's at https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/quickstarts/v1/overview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Philipe comments (suggesting use [RestSharp library](http://restsharp.org/)), would also suggest you use the [RESUMABLE endpoint](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-resumable-PUT/) instead, which is the best way to handle upload of large files.

Comment: could you please share a sample related to Resumable endpoint

Comment: you can see most of the logic at https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/view-and-data-npm/blob/master/view-and-data.js#L363